# unable to retrieve HTML form data running on Localhost:port python

Tags: python, html, sockets, http, tcp

I am running a simple form input on my localhost:port using socket programming.

Currently, I have a form running on my chrome, just a text box on localhost:2333, I am able to see the text box input on my wireshark like this
[image]

The input message I typed is testesest.
After which, I put the `<form action="http://localhost:2333">` such that the entered form data can flow back to my `localhost:port`. However, my 2nd `r= recv(1024)`is not receiving anything.

```
import socket
import sys
import os

Addr = ''
PORT = 2333
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((Addr, PORT))
s.listen()
```

The above is the standard part.

```
while(1):
    try:
        print("waiting for connection")
        conn, address = s.accept()
        print("New client connected from IP address {} and port number {}".format(*address))
        
        received = conn.recv(1024)
        #print("Request received")

        #This is what i am hosting
        #A webpage with a form
        
        
        conn.send(b'\r\n')
        
        #This is the webpage content

        
        #The code will stuck here at recv
        print("Waiting for form input from client")
        r = conn.recv(1024)
        print(r.decode())

                
        print("Form input received")
        print("HTTP response sent")


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        conn.close()
        s.close()

    conn.close()
    s.close()
    break
```

Can I get some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input data sent via `GET` is attached to the `URI` (`/?work=<data>`), which is sent as a new request:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

Addr = ''
PORT = 2333
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((Addr, PORT))
s.listen()

while (1):
    try:
        print("waiting for connection")
        conn, address = s.accept()
        print(
            "New client connected from IP address {} and port number {}".format(
                *address
            )
        )

        request = conn.recv(1024)
        print("Request received")
        method, uri, _ = request.decode().split(' ', 2)
        print(method, uri)

        #This is what i am hosting
        #A webpage with a form

        response = ""
        conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n')
        conn.send(b'Content-Type: text/html\r\n')
        conn.send(b'Host: localhost:2333\n')
        conn.send(b'\r\n')

        if uri == '/':
            response = """<html>
                <body><form action="http://localhost:2333/" method="GET">
                <input type="text" name="work"></form></body>
                </html>"""
        elif uri.startswith('/?work'):
            response = f"<html><body><h2>recevied: {uri[uri.find('/?work=')+7:]}</h2></body></html>"

        conn.send(response.encode())
        conn.send(b"\r\n")

        print("Form input received")
        #print("HTTP response sent")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        conn.close()
        s.close()

    #conn.close()
    #s.close()
    #break
```

Out:

```
waiting for connection
New client connected from IP address 127.0.0.1 and port number 55941
Request received
GET /?work=TestInput
<html><body><h2>recevied: TestInput</h2></body></html>
Form input received
waiting for connection
...
```

**Note:**
You might want to have a look at the [protocol specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) and/or use any existing library to get rid of this low level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we submit any form, browser makes new http request instead of using the existing connection, so you need to handle it in new http request/connection.

Another thing is, `r = conn.recv(1024)` is not letting the current connection close, that's why pressing enter in textfield is also not working.